# Do you think my boss disrespects me?

Tags: employer-relations

I had a terrible day: I had a problem with the printer and printed too many wrong cheques (I am a bookkeeper)and made some data entry errors in Excel. One of my supervisors asked me the previous day to complete things which required me to work overtime.  My direct boss requested to keep the void checks in her office from now on, and said that I am not required to work long hours and also noted that some people thrive working under stress.

Do you think she implied that I am not good for the job?

Comment: We are unable to read your bosses mind. You will have to ask him.

Comment: One thing I would take away from that is that the next time the other person asks you to work overtime, clear it with your direct boss.

Comment: I would feel the same way as you, but I don't think that makes us both right.  I think most people would feel the way you feel, but consider this.  Your boss didn't say you are not good for the job.  Instead your boss identified (accurately it would seem) one of your weaknesses.  She/he recognizes that your attention to detail suffered in this situation, so she/he is taking steps to avoid this situation in the future.  You should take this as indication that your contributions are valued.  You weren't fired, you were optimized.  In my opinion this is a good thing, however stressful.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone has a bad day sometimes and it sounds as though your bosses feel that you need more supervision.  I wouldn't take things too personally and just work on trying to limit problems in the future and you should find that things improve again.

We've only been told about your one day here, so we don't know the wider picture and background.  If you're having long-standing issues at work, you'll need to raise this with your boss and work out how to resolve the situation.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you think she implied that I am not good for the job?

Yes, there is no implication, she has physically taken the chequebook off you because you have lost trust.

Printing the wrong cheques as a book keeper is one of the worst things you can do. You have shown yourself to be unreliable at one of the basic core functions of your role. You will need to regain respect and trust.

Comment: I'm not sure "Yes" to this is the right and definite answer. It seems she currently wants him to work under her direct supervision to check how he works and see weither is definitively not good for the job or/and check if she can suggest way of better organizing his work to not do this kind of errors anymore.

Comment: @Walfrat We're not sure what the boss could be thinking here. I'd imagine if you failed at the most fundamental duties of your job, a manager should fire you. The fact the OP was not fired immediately, it's unclear if the manager lost trust or if the manager put the OP on notice. I'd imagine the OP would need to clarification from the manager on the things that went wrong and ensure it will not be a habit.

Answer (score -1):

It's well known that when you work too much you will make more mistakes. In some professions that doesn't matter, work counts as work and mistakes count as zero. In your profession, if you print incorrect checks (and worse if they are not caught) that's a huge negative.

So really, your boss is right that you shouldn't do overtime, because the company will actually get negative results out of it.